# Regex to find web site names which does not follow http:// or https://

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I need to find regex to find website names  which does not follow http:// or https:// 
eg

```
http://www.google.co.in  ---dont match
http://www.google.co.in  ---dont match
www.google.co.in         ---match
```

the URL can also be part of a larger string like

```
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/">www.w3schools.com</a></p>
```

or

```
The URL To be Matched is www.w3schools.com and www.abc.com , URL Not to be matched is https://www.w3schools.com/html/
```

in which `www.w3schools.com` and `www.abc.com` (In the second example)  shoud get a match, and there can be multiple urls in the string

thanks in advance

Comment: Don't parse HTML with regex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: String Is Not html, just gave it as an example, Updated the question accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need that?

```
/(?<!https:\/\/)(?<!http:\/\/)(www\.[\w-.]*?[\w-]+?(\/[\w-]*?)*?)((?=[^\w.\/-]+?)|$)+/ig
```

You can have a look here:

https://regex101.com/r/XvmR4V/4

If you have a large String that contains website names, this regex matches all names, that do not start with "http://" or "https://". Your websites names always have to start with "www"!!!

Without lookaheads and lookbehinds you can try this.
You are going to find the results in the 2. Group ($2).

```
/([^\/]{2,2})(www\.[\w-.]*?[\w-]+?(\/[\w-]*?)*?)(([^\w.\/-]+?)|$)+/ig
```

https://regex101.com/r/XvmR4V/5

Now even for www.google.de:

```
([^\/]{2,2}|^)(www\.[\w-.]*?[\w-]+?(\/[\w-]*?)*?)(([^\w.\/-]+?)|$)+
```

https://regex101.com/r/XvmR4V/6

You can replace like that.

I replaced the 'www...' with 'Test'.

```
/([^\/]{2,2}|^)(www\.[\w-.]*?[\w-]+?(\/[\w-]*?)*?)(([^\w.\/-]+?)|$)+/$1Test$4/gi
```

I testet it with the regex-Tool from IntelliJ.

My input was:

```
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">www.w3schools.com</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/html/"><a href="http://www.google.com/html/">www.google.com</a>
```

The output was:

```
<p><a href="https://www.w3schools.com/html/"><a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Test</a></p>
<p><a href="https://www.google.com/html/"><a href="http://www.google.com/html/">Test</a>
```

If it helps, it would be greate if you vote it up :-)

Comment: in the above link the regex does not work in javascript, while running im getting an error ERROR SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?^!https://)(?<!http://)(www.[w-.]*?[w-]+?(/[w-]*?)*?)((?=[^w./-]+?)|$)+/gi/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (<anonymous>)

Comment: @biff: added an other possibility to check it.

Comment: hi it was helpful, but if the string is just "www.google.com" rejex will not catch it

Comment: and it also catches strings like "www..google.com" which is wrong, can u help

Comment: @biff: adapted it :-)

Comment: my requirement is that i need to replace the matched string i.e "www.google.com" , but in this case while replacing the full match gets replaced i.e ">www.google.com<". The > &< symbols need not be replaced, any insight on that

Comment: I have got an idea for that. I write you later.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to *exclude* strings beginning with `http://` or `https://`, this is easy enough to do with a negative lookahead:

```js
var match = "www.google.co.in";
var nomatch = "http://www.google.co.in";

var re = new RegExp("^(?!https?:\/\/).*$");
if (re.test(match)) {
    console.log(match + " is valid");
}
if (re.test(nomatch)) {
    console.log(nomatch + " is valid");
}
```

One advantage of this type of pattern is that it would allow to also filter the positive match URLs on other conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression `^(http|https)://` to get the match for the string that has `http://` or `https://`. Then when you apply the match use the not `(!)` operator to reverse the match to not to include `http://` or `https://`:

```js
var regEx = new RegExp("^(http|https)://", "i");
var str = "http://www.google.co.in";
var match = !regEx.test(str);
console.log(match + ' for ' + str);

str = 'http://www.google.co.in';
match = !regEx.test(str);
console.log(match + ' for ' + str);

str = 'www.google.co.in';
match = !regEx.test(str);
console.log(match + ' for ' + str);
```